# Flutter NetworkImage widget throwing error with tmdb image url

Tags: android, flutter, socketexception

```
Image(image: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/suyNxglk17Cpk8rCM2kZgqKdftk.jpg")),
Image(image: NetworkImage("https://spiderimg.amarujala.com/assets/images/2018/08/17/saheed-path_1534491687.jpeg")),
```

I have the above two Image widgets in a column. But the first image is giving `Exception caught by image resource service` error while the second image loads without any issue. Why am i getting this issue with the tmdb image? I am able to open the image without any issues on my browser

I have seen other threads where people fix this error by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` on the manifest. But i have already added it else other images won't load. I suspect it is something specific to tmdb image.

[image]

Full Error Stack :

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed host lookup: 'image.tmdb.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:677:35)
#1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1680:26)
#2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
#3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:237:22)
#4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:60:28)
#5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2437:24)
#6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2805:12)
#7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2810:12)
#8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2694:12)
#9      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2573:48)
#10     NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
#11     NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#12     ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#13     ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:380:22)
#14     ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:83)
#15     ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
#16     ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
#17     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:464:26)
#18     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
#19     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:461:11)
#23     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:453:16)
#24     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
#25     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1187:16)
#26     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1139:5)
#27     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4826:11)
#28     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4638:5)
#29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3673:14)
#30     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6333:36)
#31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3425:18)
#32     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5758:32)
#33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6356:17)
#34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#37     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#44     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#45     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#47     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#48     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#49     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#51     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#52     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#53     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#54     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#56     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#57     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#58     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#60     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1242:37)
#61     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1147:35)
#62     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:35)
#63     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1191:24)
#64     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1125:7)
#65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#67     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#68     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5700:32)
#69     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6356:17)
#70     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:228:11)
#71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#72     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#73     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#74     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#76     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#78     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#79     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#80     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#81     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#82     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#83     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#84     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#85     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#86     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#87     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#88     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#89     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#90     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#91     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#92     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#93     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#95     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#96     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#97     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#99     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#100    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#101    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#102    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#103    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#104    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#106    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#107    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#108    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#109    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#110    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#111    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#115    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#117    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#118    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#119    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#120    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#121    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#122    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#123    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#124    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#125    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#126    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#127    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#128    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#129    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#130    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#131    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#133    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5700:32)
#134    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6356:17)
#135    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#136    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#137    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#138    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#139    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#140    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#141    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#142    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#143    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#144    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#145    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#146    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#147    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#148    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#149    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#150    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#151    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#152    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#153    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#154    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#156    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#157    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#158    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#341    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#342    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#343    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#344    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#345    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#346    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#347    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#348    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#349    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#350    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:5)
#351    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#352    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6202:14)
#353    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#354    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#355    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#356    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#357    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#358    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#359    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#360    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5020:5)
#361    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#362    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#363    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#364    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#365    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#366    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#367    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#368    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#369    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#370    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4872:5)
#371    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3412:15)
#372    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:16)
#373    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4840:11)
#374    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:5)
#375    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:33)
#376    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#377    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#378    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#379    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#380    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 7 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/suyNxglk17Cpk8rCM2kZgqKdftk.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/suyNxglk17Cpk8rCM2kZgqKdftk.jpg", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```